# How to ignore mac language hotkeys in godot4 game?

Tags: macos, godot4

I am making a godot4 parkour game on my macbook. And everytime I press control(crouch) + space(jump), my mac opens up the language change menu. How do I disable that menu in my game? So that my players will not experience this issue?

the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind these universal keyboard shortcuts in `System Settings/Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts`. To know more about them go to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236.

However, if you want to do that programmatically, there is no easy API for that other than parse the file at:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`

and modify the shortcut you want. But for that, you need to know what they mean:

[what do the parameter values in AppleSymbolicHotKeys plist dict represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878482/what-do-the-parameter-values-in-applesymbolichotkeys-plist-dict-represent)

However, even if you make those changes, they will not take effect without restarting. To avoid that, you can do what is recommended here:

https://zameermanji.com/blog/2021/6/8/applying-com-apple-symbolichotkeys-changes-instantaneously/

Therefore, if I were you, I would just recommend users to go to system settings and turn those bindings off.

Comment: is there a way to turn it off for the program? Because I don't want all my players doing that.

Comment: As I said, there is no API for that. You need to scan the file com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist and edit out those bindings as I explained in my answer.